# .htaccess mod_rewrite Convert file to php and don't show filetype

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Given a set of URL as follows:

```
http://site.com/filename.html
http://site.com/filename.htm
http://site.com/filename.php
http://site.com/filename
```

Using the mod_rewrite module in .htaccess, how can I make it request the file at

```
http://site.com/filename.php
```

and show the URL

```
http://site.com/filename
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>This should satisfy your requirements:</strike>

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

---

EDIT: After your comment and changes in the question - try this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\. /$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: http://site.com/filename.html, http://site.com/filename.htm gives me a 404 with that.  http://site.com/filename appears as http://site.com/filename.php.  Does not satisfy the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Try these rules:

```
# remove file name extension and redirect externally
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]+\.(html?|php)
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.(html?|php)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# rewrite to PHP file internally
RewriteRule ^[^.]+$ $0.php [L]
```